# I am at a crossroads in my program and I was wondering which path would be more efficient time wise

Tags: performance, algorithm

I currently see two ways to code the next step of my program and there are probably more, but the two routes I have are as follows.

1. I take the factors of the lowest number and loop through the other numbers two see if they share those common factors.
2. I find the factors of the lowest number and add it to a list. I then find the factors of the other numbers that do not exceed the lowest and add them to the same list. I then run through the list to check which is the highest number that appears x times.

I am leaning towards 1, but I'm not sure.

Sorry if this is too ambiguous, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is x in 2.?

Comment: yes, problem is not well presented. You're not even saying what you want / are supposed to do, you just present two solutions out of the blue to a problem you haven't defined. You should 1) present the problem 2) present your ideas to solve it and 3) ask what is the best option.

Comment: Why would you not take 2 minutes to write out what problem you are working on? The way you have written it means that even if people take the trouble to help you, no one else will be able to find your question even if they are working on the same problem. Two people have generously voted up your question, and others have answered it, but neither makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given the ambiguity, as stated: the 1st requires less steps and avoids the allocation of a data structure.